# Pointer to const

Tags: c++, c

**Constant's are supposed to be in read-only memory ,then how is a pointer to const able to change its value .**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
const int c=10;
int* p=&c;

*p=1;

printf("c:%d",c);//value of const changed.
return 0;
}
```

Output:
c:1

compiler:gcc 4.8.5

Comment: Don't ignore the compiler warning C4090: 'initializing' : different 'const' qualifiers. The `const` is a compiler thing: there is no physical read-only protection (otherwise it would be impossible to initialise)..

Comment: *"**Constant's are supposed to be in read-only memory**"* **The compiler can put it wherever it wants.**

Comment: The code you posted [should give you a compiler error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8943bf047a35ab15).

Comment: This code should be giving compilation error.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Including no-where, in some cases :)

Comment: @Gopi: _"Pointer to a constant and dereferencing it is undefined behavior"_ Huh?

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl: No, not in C. But you compiled it as C++. Here's a fixed link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d6cb82251fa4d7d

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It came out wrong with words. I meant to say having a pointer to a constant and trying to modify it's value using a pointer is wrong. Of-course you can dereference and read the value